# how to override jquery autocomplete menu item menufocus event function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am looking to override "menufocus" event which gets triggered on arrow key up or down on items.

```js
//providing below extension autocomplete functions
//issue is even the default jquery ui autocomplete menufocus is getting executed 
// before the below menufocus function 
$.widget( "app.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
                _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
        
                    // Replace the matched text with a custom span. This
                    // span uses the class found in the "highlightClass" option.
                    var re = new RegExp( "(" + this.term + ")", "gi" ),
                        cls = 'ui-autocomplete-term',
                        template = "<span class='" + cls + "'>$1</span>",
                        label = item.label.replace( re, template ),
                        $li = $( "<li/>" ).appendTo( ul );
                    
                    // Create and return the custom menu item content.
                    $( "<a/>" ).attr( "href", "#" )
                               .html( label )
                               .appendTo( $li );

                    var hasRcSpan = $(".find-fund-search-btn-rc");
                    if(typeof(hasRcSpan) != 'undefined' && hasRcSpan != null){
                        $('#' + uniqueId + '-search-icon').show();
                    }else{
                        $('#' + uniqueId + '-search-icon').hide();
                    }

                    return $li;
                },
                
                _create: function() {
                    this._super();
                    this._on( this.menu.element, {
                        menufocus: function( event, ui ) {
                            console.log("menu focus called");
                            var label, item;
                            item = ui.item.data( "ui-autocomplete-item" );
                            // Announce the value in the liveRegion
                            label = ui.item.attr( "aria-label" ) || item.value;
                            if ( label && String.prototype.trim.call( label ).length ) {
                                clearTimeout( this.liveRegionTimer );
                                this.liveRegionTimer = this._delay( function() {
                                    this.liveRegion.html( $( "<div>" ).text( label ) );
                                }, 100 );
                            }
                        },
                    });
                }
                
            });
```

saw some examples on autocomplete search input field focus, response , select but not on "menufocus" event.

This is jquery js https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js, which has "autocomplete" widget js.

thanks,
sri

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: When I test your code, I get `ReferenceError: uniqueId is not defined` in the `_renderItem` function.

Answer (score 0):

Made some minor changes and tested the code.

```js
$(function() {

  $.widget("custom.myAutocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
      this._super();
      console.log(this.menu.element);
      this._on(this.menu.element, {
        menufocus: function(event, ui) {
          console.log("menu focus called");
          var label, item;
          item = ui.item.data("ui-autocomplete-item");
          label = ui.item.attr("aria-label") || item.value;
          if (label && String.prototype.trim.call(label).length) {
            clearTimeout(this.liveRegionTimer);
            this.liveRegionTimer = this._delay(function() {
              this.liveRegion.html($("<div>").text(label));
            }, 100);
          }
        },
      });
    },
    _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
      var re = new RegExp("(" + this.term + ")", "gi"),
        cls = 'ui-autocomplete-term',
        template = "<span class='" + cls + "'>$1</span>",
        label = item.label.replace(re, template),
        $li = $("<li/>").appendTo(ul);
      $("<a/>").attr("href", "#")
        .html(label)
        .appendTo($li);
      var hasRcSpan = $(".find-fund-search-btn-rc");
      /*
      if (typeof(hasRcSpan) != 'undefined' && hasRcSpan != null) {
        $('#' + uniqueId + '-search-icon').show();
      } else {
        $('#' + uniqueId + '-search-icon').hide();
      }
      */
      return $li;
    }
  });

  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];
  $("#tags").myAutocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

This appears to be working as you desired.